# Attempted to move folder. Where did my files go?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, file-transfer

So I have had this "stuff" folder on my C: drive (Windows 7 ultimate) which has grown into the tens of gigs.

Since the C: drive only had about a gig left, I got a new drive. 
Just installed it. 
When I formatted it, there were over ten "You must format this drive in order to use it" windows. I cancelled a dozen windows and just used the one remaining to format the drive.

Since the formatting went well and the drive seemed to work (created and deleted files/folders), I cut/pasted the large "stuff" folder with many documents (tens of gigs) onto it.

*The operation was done in a split second* and resulted in an empty folder with the correct name.

This can happen with a bad drive and I didn't take the first warning sign, but what is really weird is that the folder disappeared from the C: drive, **but the disk space was not freed**.

The files must be on the C: drive. CheckDisk did not find anything. The disk show 1% defrag. 
I checked the size of the folder that contained the "stuff" folder, and it was very small.

How do I proceeed to locate the files. Or, if the files are gone, how do I proceed to actually make the disk space available?

Nothing in the trash can.

Comment: I recently ran into a similar problem. Do you need the folder structure of your files?

Comment: The structure is not that important. The files themselves is what is important. If that cannot be done, then at least getting the vacated disk space

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cgsecurity.org/ has two tools that may help you, TestDisk and PhotoRec. TestDisk is for attempting to recover the error to the hard drive, photorec is for recovering data. I suggest these tools because they are free and open source.

Because you don't need the folder structure, I would just use PhotoRec to recover the files and then format the drive, which should solve the othe issue.

(TestDisk is a bit complicated, PhotoRec is pretty straightforward)

Comment: Thanks. I will check into that tonight. I surmised that the move operation had temporarily moved the files to another place in the folder structure as part of the move command and that they were residing in a temp directory somewhere. As we all know, moving files internally on a disk is fast because it's just pointer juggling.
If the files were actually deleted (as in: the disk space on C: was freed), I would have been checking out "undelete" tools.
But I will check them out. Thanks